# Table View still blank?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a problem with my tableview. I'm trying to make a program that downloads job details from my database and lists them. The tableview is still blank, the view is connected to the specific controller and I have checked that the JSON feed and cell identifier are OK. My cell rows are also strange, the row lines continue over the right edge though I have aligned the tableview object correctly. I had similar problems with my previous project but didn't know what was wrong.

Here is a part of the code (Source from: http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/)

**JobViewer.m**

```
@interface JobViewer()
{
    NSMutableData *_downloadedData;
}
@end

@implementation JobViewer

- (void)downloadItems
{
    // Getting json file
    NSURL *jsonFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"here is my correct URL"];

    //Making request
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileURL];

    //Creating NSURLConnection with the request
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    //Initialize data
    _downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //Append the data that was downloaded
    [_downloadedData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //Creating array for the information
    NSMutableArray *_jobs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Parsing the JSON file
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    //Looping through JSON objects and storing them into array
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonObject = jsonArray[i];

        //Creating a new object and getting data from JSON element
        Job *newJob = [[Job alloc] init];
        newJob.jobid = jsonObject[@"Job_id"];
        newJob.companyid = jsonObject[@"Company_id"];
        newJob.customer = jsonObject[@"Customer"];
        newJob.phone = jsonObject[@"Phone"];
        newJob.email = jsonObject[@"Email"];
        newJob.address = jsonObject[@"Address"];
        newJob.city = jsonObject[@"City"];
        newJob.header = jsonObject[@"Header"];
        newJob.notes = jsonObject[@"Notes"];
        newJob.date = jsonObject[@"Date"];
        newJob.driver = jsonObject[@"Driver"];

        //Added question to array
        [_jobs addObject:newJob];
    }

    // Passing the done data and passing items back
    if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_jobs];
    }

}

@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
@interface MainViewController ()

{
     JobViewer *_jobViewer;
     NSArray *_listObjects;
}

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.mainList.delegate = self;
     self.mainList.dataSource = self;

     _listObjects = [[NSArray alloc] init];
     _jobViewer = [[JobViewer alloc] init];
     _jobViewer.delegate = self;
     [_jobViewer downloadItems];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

 - (void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
 {

     _listObjects = items;
     [self.mainList reloadData];

 }

 #pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods
// You may remove this method
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

     return _listObjects.count;

 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     NSString *cellIdentifier = @"InfoCell";
     UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

     Job *item = _listObjects[indexPath.row];

     newCell.textLabel.text = item.address;

     //[newCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

     return newCell;

 }

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: "the row lines continue over the right edge" That's interesting; what does that mean? I don't know what you think a "row line" is; could you post a picture and provide a link?

Comment: Hi! That could be just my bad English but here's the picture of the "rows": http://jessetakkinen.kapsi.fi/public_html/rows.png

Comment: in general, I NSLog the data and hardcode a dictionary to output the first row which gets me through the issues mentioned by dfmuir.

Comment: @JesseTakkinen Thanks for the screen shot! I don't see anything "continue over the right edge". The table view looks perfectly fine except that the cells are empty. So you only have one problem, not two problems. :)

Comment: @matt I checked the lines in the Mail app, and now I see that the cell lines supposed to be like that, there's a little empty space before the line starts, so now I have at least one problem less. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I solved the problem! I had written connectionDidFinishDownloading instead of connectionDidFinishLoading, which is the method to use. Thanks for the NSLog tip @timpone , I found it very useful.

Comment: np - that's def one of shortcomings of XCode autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add "InfoCell" as the reuse identifier in your Storyboard.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If you mean the Identifier field in the Attributes Inspector, I have already set it as "InfoCell".

Answer (score 0):

Probably your tableView doesn't recognise the cell so you should add the cell at `tableView` in the storyboard and it is called "**InfoCell**"

If you don't want to add cell into `tableView` in the storyboard and you have a xib with your cell. you can call in your viewController this method:

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"IndoCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"IndoCell"];
```

that if your nib is called "`IndoCell.xib`"